# How long is a "round" in Daggerfall?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-ii-daggerfall

When using the Spell Maker in Daggerfall, spell duration is listed in "rounds", rather than seconds or minutes.  Exactly how long is a round?

I haven't been able to find any direct explanation online, including whether the round duration is affected by things like the Reflexes setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did just test it on a very high reflexes game and the best i can come up with is the duration equals (number of rounds + 1) x 5 seconds.

On a lvl 5 character, a spell with 1 + 1 / 20 level lasted 10 seconds, a spell with 1 + 1 / level duration lasted 35 seconds.

Comment: sorry if it's not clear to me but how how long is a round? 5 seconds?

Comment: @gyozokudor yes, that's correct.